can't find CharacterSet when trying to start-dev locally
I've just cloned keycloak and followed the readme. It builds ok but won't run.
Readme says run the following cmd to start (java -jar quarkus/server/target/lib/quarkus-run.jar start-dev) but I get the following error...
ERROR: Unexpected error when starting the server in (development) mode
Error details:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:200)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:549)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain.start(KeycloakMain.java:146)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.command.AbstractStartCommand.run(AbstractStartCommand.java:57)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2030)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2465)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2457)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2419)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2277)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2421)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2174)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.run(Picocli.java:147)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.parseAndRun(Picocli.java:135)
        at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain.main(KeycloakMain.java:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/CharacterSet
        at io.quarkus.jdbc.oracle.runtime.OracleInitRecorder.setupCharSets(OracleInitRecorder.java:21)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ExtendedCharactersSupport$preinitializeCharacterSets1608602642.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ExtendedCharactersSupport$preinitializeCharacterSets1608602642.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.CharacterSet
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:114)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:72)
        ... 30 more

I'm going to assume this has something to do with an Oracle JDBC library but there's no mention in the readme of it.
I've also tried with the release/26.0 branch, same issue.

Make sure that the Oracle JDBC driver is in the classpath and accessible. What version of the JDBC driver are you using?

I'm not. Just trying to run keycloak.

Encountering the same issue

I was facing the same error. The following command worked for me:
./mvnw -f testsuite/utils/pom.xml exec:java -Pkeycloak-server 

This is mentioned in the build.md file of Keycloak before the last commit.

Keycloak removed oracle driver out of the box to be compliant to its license agreement. To solve this error just add the oracle driver dependency by removing the added exclusion quarkus/runtime.
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.oracle.database.nls</groupId>
                <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

You just need to remove exclusion section
